# How to get WHQL certification for a file driver for multiple Windows versions?

Tags: driver, sign, minifilter, filefilter

I made a small file protector driver by VC++, but I see Microsoft require all drivers to be signed with WHQL to install on most of latest Windows versions. I checked Hardware Lab Kit (HLK) and HCK documents and it seems the only way to get the WHQL certification is to install the HLK/HCK on every Windows version I want users to use the driver on. That means I have to install every Windows server versions and Desktop versions such as Win7/8/10.

I am an indie developer and already have a EV certification to sign the driver, so is there an easier way to get WHQL certification for a file driver for multiple Windows versions? Or there is no way to create and distribute filefilter drivers by indie developers in the future?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout https://github.com/HCK-CI - this is a framework to automate HLK\HCK certification process.

Comment: Thank Yan. But how to use this HCK-CI ?

Comment: Introduction to HCK-CI: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LUfG-gZVbPM , Installation: https://github.com/HCK-CI/AutoHCK-Installer/wiki , usage: https://github.com/HCK-CI/AutoHCK/wiki